# How can I ensure that binaries installed by my install script are executable?

Tags: github

I've just created my first github repository: https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome

I've uploaded all the files but have concerns with how the end-user will copy them after download.

Here is the `copy-files` script (abridged) they would run:

```bash
!/bin/sh

if [ $(id -u) != 0 ]; then # root powers needed to call this script
    echo >&2 $0 must be called with sudo powers
    exit 1
fi

cp -v ./eyesome.sh              /usr/local/bin/
cp -v ./eyesome-cfg.sh          /usr/local/bin/
cp -v ./eyesome-src.sh          /usr/local/bin/
cp -v ./eyesome-sun.sh          /usr/local/bin/
cp -v ./wake-eyesome.sh         /usr/local/bin/
cp -v ./start-eyesome           /etc/cron.d/
cp -v ./daily-eyesome-sun       /etc/cron.daily/
cp -v ./systemd-wake-eyesome    /lib/systemd/system-sleep/

exit 0
```

My first thought is after someone downloads the files none are marked as executable?

The `copy-files` script has a section for "uninstalling" that is inactive. Is this a common courtesy to provide?

Comments on further reading to improve my `github` and refine my `copy-files` code are also appreciated.

Comment: Generally speaking, this kind of question is off-topic here. It's primarily opinion-based and too broad, and also may require us to go off-site to fully understand it. But I'll interpret it this way: "How can I ensure that binaries installed by my install script become executable?" In the future, please try to stay on-topic as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You say: "My first thought is after someone downloads the files none are marked as executable?"   `git` allows you to mark the files executable and preserve permissions. Before doing `git commit -a -m 'Some changes';git push`  just run `chmod +x` on the files.
2. Currently all your files are in top level of directory. This looks kinda messy and disorganized. It's best to have directories and organize things. If you look at professional organizations, they have `doc/`, `scr/` directories, or at least project's top level module name directory  with submodules inside.

   When user downloads zip file and extracts everything, what will they see ? Tons of files scatered all over the directory where they extracted it. So having directories in your project helps to minimize the clutter.

   Some repositories I have do follow same thing - everything is in top level. But I don't change that because I already have instructions written in my Ask Ubuntu answers, so going back and trying to figure out what answers to change is too problematic.
3. Have an installation script. Instead of writing too many instructions to the user, this one thing can save time for them and you.
4. Figure out how to use `develop` and `master` branches. You can keep a working version in `master` and work on changes in `develop`. That way users have working code, and you're not freaking out about code being broken and users unhappy.
5. Your `README.md` is bare. Add some useful information. Particularly, outline things that are necessary as dependencies for the project, specifically commands not installed on default Ubuntu system ( which is what your projects generally tend to aim at).

Comment: Lots to digest. Can you provide a link to a sample "installation script"? I haven't created any doc yet. That will take a week with .GIF's, etc.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  Not really, at least not anything good. I've an [install script for lks-indicator](https://github.com/SergKolo/lks-indicator/blob/master/install.sh) which I used to use before I figured out debian packaging is a bit more suitable for my needs. I'd probably  do things a lot differently now than back then.  The `install` command suggested in Chris's answer should be one of the things in the script itself. Permissions, checking if certain commands are installed, etc. - all that can be done in install scripts

Comment: I've just uploaded new version of `copy-files` to github using Chris's suggestion. I thought creating a `.deb` would be a lot of work? Especially since there are no program dependencies on libraries and what not. Thanks for pointing out not to use your lks-indicator install script and opt for something more robust.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It depends. For shell scripts - making a `.deb` is some work, but if you do things right  you can make one in less than an hour.  For  Python, there's ways to automate it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look around for a GUI or CLI script to automate the process of creating a .deb script for < 10 files to 4 directories.

Comment: OK call me crazy but as in the past I'm following in your footsteps and repeating some of your mistakes. I created a script `install.sh` that copies files, remove files, verify hash checksums, publishes files and creates hash checksums, with help screen: https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome/blob/master/install.sh Also what if someone else used `eyesome` name in github for totally unrelated blogs. Should I be concerned?

Comment: I've posted a rudimentary `readme.MD` which uses psuedo-stack exchange syntax I discovered. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `cp`, take a look at [`install`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/install), e.g.

```
install ./eyesome.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

By default, it will use mode 755, but you can override that with the `-m` option if you need something different.

The next logical step would probably be to build a proper package for the operating system(s) you're targeting.

Comment: I should have mentioned installing to Ubuntu / Debian. Programs are all in bash. Bash Arrays are used so version must be >= 4 I think. Version 4 is almost a decade old so I didn't test for it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, what does any of that have to do with my recommendation? Ubuntu ships with the [`install` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/install.1.html).

Comment: I was responding to your answer part: *"The next logical step would probably be to build a proper package for the operating system(s) you're targeting."*

Comment: I've implemented your `install` technique and I think it works like a charm. I've also changed the script name from `copy-files` to `install.sh` and added extra features: https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome/blob/master/install.sh Thanks for your help :)